# Install Enterprise ios app without having to trust in device management

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise-distribution

I have developed an app for my client using Enterprise Account. Normally, a user needs to install the app and on first run, he/she needs to trust the enterprise developer by going in Settings -> General -> Device management  and trust the developer. Is this the one and only way, an enterprise app can be run at first or there are ways, where there is no need of all this process for a general user?

Comment: Use jailbreak otherwise no way.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no way to escape this part any app run on iPhone (with any way other than app store download ) will have to be trusted so it can be installed

Comment: The only exception would be if the enterprise app is installed as a managed app via MDM.